# PCI DSS 2020 Google Cloud Official documentation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Can anyone assist me to find out PCI DSS 2020 or latest from Google Cloud Kubernetes?

I found this https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/pci-dss
But it seems 2018 update.

```
Observe the time-related system-parameter settings for a sample of system components to verify:
•  Only the designated central time server(s) receives time signals from external sources, and time signals from external sources are based on International Atomic Time or UTC.
•  Where there is more than one designated time server, the designated central time server(s) peer with one another to keep accurate time.
•  Systems receive time only from designated central time server(s).
```

I need those 3 requirements exist in latest update of PCI-DSS Google Cloud, however i found it in 2018 documentation. Or maybe the 2018 is as the latest update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current standard is PCI DSS v3.2.1 May 2018. The next release is expected to be PCI DSS 4.0 in mid 2021.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for enlightening me. https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2-1.pdf